# What does a SELECT statement without FROM used for?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am analyzing a stored procedure.
There I came across a `SELECT` statement as below.

```
select @msg = 'spid: ' + convert(varchar(12), @@spid) + ' pre mat pull - PRODUCT_WORK COUNT = ' + convert(char(6), @@rowcount)
```

What does this statement without `FROM` do? How does it work? When do we use it?

Can't we use `SET` instead of `SELECT`?

Please help.

Answer (score 8):

`SELECT` with no table will generate a result set projecting the columns and values that you've specified - this can be bound to a result set or reader in an application, in the same way that a table-bound `SELECT` works.

`SELECT` with no table is [not an ANSI standard](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28530/5489) and will only work in certain RDBMS's (like `SqlServer`), but not all - e.g. Oracle's `SELECT` requires a table, but provides a pseudo table `DUAL` for this purpose.

It can also be used for assignment in `SqlServer` - `SELECT` will allow assignment of multiple variables in one statement:

```
SELECT @SomeVar = 1234, @AnotherVar = 'Foo';
```

Comment: One more with this, is that you can use it to union variables into result sets. ie... select <vars> union all select <columns> from <table>

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you can use `set` instead of `select`. But with `select` you can assign multiple variables at once, like

```
select @msg = 'msg', @data = 'data
```

Answer (score 1):

You must understand the @ and @@

```
@msg = local variable 

@@spid and  @@rowcount = global variable
```

the set and select is almost same but the select can get value from DB. and Set cannot get value from DB.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be the simplest one since the answer is very general.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT TOP(1) MAX(Score) AS High FROM Players),
    (SELECT TOP(1) MIN(Score) AS Low FROM Players)
```

This will show you only a row like this

```
    High  |   Low
```

---

```
1     98  |    26
```