# In PostgreSQL how do I create a function that returns an actual table?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

In PostgreSQL how do I create a function that returns an actual table?

For example, if I have the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cols(_table_name TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE (column_name TEXT,
               data_type TEXT) AS
$$

SELECT column_name,
       data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = _table_name
ORDER BY column_name
;

$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

And the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (a TEXT, b INTEGER, c NUMERIC);
```

If I run `SELECT cols('test');` I get:

```
    cols
-------------
 (a,text)
 (b,integer)
 (c,numeric)
(3 rows)
```

But I would like to be able to get:

```
 column_name | data_type
-------------+-----------
 a           | text
 b           | integer
 c           | numeric
(3 rows)
```

Comment: @jdigital That did solve my problem but I still don't know if it fully answered my question.  Also, how did you find that? Because I searched on Google, and SO, and was thorough looking through the similar questions links.

Comment: I did a google search for "postgres return table".  I wasn't familiar with this and wanted to learn more.

Comment: Perhaps this will help with the rest of your question: you're doing a SELECT without a FROM, see here:  [What does a SELECT statement without FROM used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155475/what-does-a-select-statement-without-from-used-for)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is fine, it's how you're calling it.

Instead of:

```
SELECT cols('test');
```

use

```
SELECT * FROM cols('test');
```